# Cant convert a .ttf font into an asset in Unity TMP font asset converter

Tags: unity-game-engine, fonts, textmeshpro

So I want to create a custom font for my Unity project but I had multiple projects where I would get a random star shape for each character glyph for the font I wanted to use, including my current project.

I tried multiple things like changing and reimporting the font file, reimporting text mesh pro, adjusting the font asset converter, and other slighter changes but I am still stuck.

I would truly appreciate any and all help for this problem!

Comment: is it the same for all fonts? ive never had an issue but then i always stuck with the good ole norms.  is it a specific font that doesnt?

Comment: no, i havent gotten any font to work yet, i used this in multiple projects but still didnt get the wanted result. I heard its a very common problem but none of the solutions work.

Comment: when you import it what does it look like, cos mine seems to work https://imgur.com/WjUEpqk

Comment: it looks like a normal font asset and then whenever i convert it to a tmp asset in the windows- textmeshpro-font asset converter     generate as tmp, and save it as a tmp asset it is replaced with a star shape

Comment: no idea, that seems to be a you thing then

Comment: found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, it does not work in the built in asset font converter, but after a little bit of searching i found another simple solution,   **selecting the font asset and pressing ctrl+shift+F12 it automaticaly converts it into a tmp font**

[Found the solution in this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/use-other-fonts-in-textmesh-pro.527960/)

Comment: well thats darn freaky - you might want to note which version of unity you're on too cos that actually doesnt sound normal - especially as mine worked even on the latest alpha